# Copying multiple S3 files in parallel using aws shell command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

Any improvements to this welcome, I have got it working and I'm happy with it. I'm not really all that  proficient with bash shell scripts though.

Problem:
AWS can copy multiple files pretty much as quickly as it can copy one file, so if you have a lot of large files then the best way is to get Amazon to copy them in parallel.

Solution:
Run the `aws s3 cp` or `mv` commands as background processes, and monitor them for completion. Limit the number that can be run in parallel.

```
# Check for aws s3 commands running that are owned by this shell process
function counts3 #
{
    local plist=( $( ps -ef | grep -E "aws s3 \w+ " | awk "\$3 == $$ { print \$2 }" ) )
    echo ${#plist[@]}
}

# Submit an aws s3 process in the background, if there are fewer than "n" currently running
function multis3 # (threads cp|mv source target [other params]...)
{
    local threads=$1;shift

    # Turn off monitor mode so you don't get the nohup completion output
    set +m
    
    local pcount=$(counts3)
    # Wait until there are fewer s3 commands running than the threads limit
    while (( ${pcount} > ${threads} )) || (( ${pcount} == ${threads} )) ; do
        sleep 1
        pcount=`counts3`
    done
    # Run the command, as there is now below the limit
    nohup aws s3 $@ >& /dev/null &
    # Introduce a small delay to stagger the start of the cp/mv commands
    sleep 1
}

# Check if there are any aws s3 processes running, and wait until there aren't
function multis3wait #
{
    local pcount=$(counts3)
    # Wait until there are no s3 commands running
    while (( ${pcount} > 0 )) ; do
        sleep 1
        pcount=`counts3`
    done

    # Turn monitor mode back on again
    set -m
}
```

Usage example, instead of this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-1.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-1.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-2.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-2.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-3.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-3.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-4.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-4.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-5.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-5.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-6.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-6.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-7.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-7.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-8.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-8.txt
aws s3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-9.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-9.txt
```

do this:

```
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-1.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-1.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-2.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-2.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-3.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-3.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-4.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-4.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-5.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-5.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-6.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-6.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-7.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-7.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-8.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-8.txt
multis3 3 cp s3://from_bucket/from_path/file-9.txt s3://to_bucket/to_path/file-9.txt
multis3wait
```

The `3` is the number of permitted threads. This can be as high as you like, 3 is just an example, but I have found that going over 50 doesn't really gain much. You can also do `mv` instead of or as well as `cp`.

Remember, if you put these functions in a shell library script (e.g. `multis3.sh`) you need to do this first to load the functions:

```
. multis3.sh
```

Perhaps I should remove the `set +m` and `set -m` and leave that up to the calling script to decide.

Alternative approaches

- Gnu `parallel` can be used to run the `aws s3` commands
- The `aws s3 sync` command will use the `max_concurrent_requests` setting to copy multiple files in parallel

I still feel that this library has a place, as it allows finer control over what gets copied than `aws s3 sync` (and can do `mv` as well as `cp`), and the advantage over `parallel` is that you can kick off a buch of copy commands, do something else in the script, and then wait for them all to complete before doing something that needs the files.

Possible enhancements

This could be generalised to run any process, and just count the number of child processes without filtering for `aws s3`. The child process count would have to exclude the `ps` command that is counting child processes...

Comment: It is great that you implemented this as a shell library.  That will give you the most flexibility with reusing this code in the long term.  Kudos.

Comment: Would you not get the same advantage with GNU Parallel simply by using `&` and `wait`: `parallel ... & do other stuff; wait; do stuff that need the cp to finish`?

Comment: GNU parallel might work, but I'd have to prepare a file or variable with all the commands and feed them all in at the same time. With this, I can drip feed the files in a shell. I sometimes do this manually, prepare a few hundred commands and paste 50 at a time into a shell and let the multis3 command manage it.

Comment: Doesn't `aws s3 cp` use the max_concurrent_requests setting? Have you tested setting for `cp`?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#max-concurrent-requests

Comment: Gosh @Munesh it's a long time since I did anything with S3, I think I've forgotten nearly everything I knew about it.